# Prolog DCG for parsing escaped sequences

Tags: parsing, prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I need to parse the string `^borrow$ ^\$500$` into the list `[borrow, $500]`. The grammar I wrote so far is

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

write_list([]).
write_list([H|T]) :- atom_codes(S, H), write(S), nl, write_list(T).

% Grammar.
tags([Tag|Rest]) --> string(_), tag(Tag), tags(Rest).
tags([]) --> string(_).
tag(Tag) --> "^", tag_contents(Tag), "$".
tag_contents(Tag) --> string(Tag).
```

Which works when I don't have `\$` inside a token:

```
?- phrase(tags(T), "^pisica$ ^catel$"), write_list(T).
pisica
catel
?- phrase(tags(T), "^borrow$ ^\\$500$"), write_list(T).
borrow
\
```

What is the best practice for parsing this kind of escaped sequences with Prolog DCGs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that tag_contents//1 captures just the backslash, and then $ acts a tag stop in parent call.

Here is a ugly hack around this problem:

```
tag(Tag1) -->
   "^", tag_contents(Tag), [C], "$", {C \= 0'\\, append(Tag, [C], Tag1) }.
```

*edit*

a somewhat better one:

```
tag(Tag) --> "^", tag_contents(Tag), "$", {\+last(Tag, 0'\\)}.
```

*edit*

'best practice' is of course to handle nested content with contextual rules. You need more code tough...

```
tag(Tag) --> "^", tag_contents(Tag).

tag_contents([0'\\,C|Cs]) --> "\\", [C], !, tag_contents(Cs).
tag_contents([]) --> "$".
tag_contents([C|Cs]) --> [C], tag_contents(Cs).
```

Comment: Sorry to spoil this, but tags//1 which uses tag//1 is incorrect.